# openfiledialogs interfere and directories persist

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I have a program (C#, .Net 4.5, WPF) that has uses files from several different paths.  In order to allow the user to browse to the location for that file type, I instantiated a different OpenFileDialog for each in hopes that each would keep track separately of its last used directory.

```
    //Class variables
OpenFileDialog wordFileDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
OpenFileDialog excelFileDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
Dictionary<FILETYPES, OpenFileDialog> fdialogs = new Dictionary<FILETYPES, OpenFileDialog>();

//from Main
wordFileDlg.FilterIndex = 2;
wordFileDlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
wordFileDlg.Title = "Choose Word Document Template";
wordFileDlg.Filter = "All files (*.docx)|*.docx";

excelFileDlg.FilterIndex = 2;
excelFileDlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
excelFileDlg.Title = "Choose Excel or XML Data File";
excelFileDlg.Filter = "All files (*.xls*;*.xml)|*.xls*;*.xml";

wordFileDlg.InitialDirectory = @"d:\downloads-tmp\";
excelFileDlg.InitialDirectory = @"D:\Document\Spreadsheets";

fdialogs[FILETYPES.WORD] = wordFileDlg;
fdialogs[FILETYPES.EXCEL] = excelFileDlg;
//... End Main


private string browseForFile(FILETYPES filetype, out string result)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Using OpenFileDialog with initial dir = " + fdialogs[filetype].InitialDirectory);
    DialogResult dr;

    dr = fdialogs[filetype].ShowDialog();
    result = dr.ToString();
    Trace.WriteLine("Dialog result dr= " + dr.ToString()+", type of dr = ");
    if (!dr.ToString().Equals("Cancel"))
    {
        clearWarning();
    }
    return fdialogs[filetype].FileName;
}
```

This seems to work intermittently.  Sometimes when I select a file from one file dialog (wordFileDlg), the next time I open the other file dialog (excelFileDlg) the directory has changed to the last selected directory of wordFileDlg.  The other way around isn't true.  Why would it do that?

I set the initial directory property to a default value, but even the last directory seems to persist across sessions.  I set the restoreDirectory property to false I open the program, browse for some files and close the program.  I open the program again and the browse does not take me to the initial directory, but back to the last selected directory.  How does it even know?  I can't seem to find a way to open the file dialog to a specific directory.  I've tried setting RestoreDirectory to both true and false.

How can I have different file dialogs remember their own directories and NOT persist across sessions, and can I set the directory it opens to?

Comment: You can't. You're fighting with the OS, which wants to presume that the user will want to open the next file from the same location. You won't win this argument.

Comment: The two dialogs open in different folders, so something else is going on here.  Has someone made an open source file browser class that I can subclass or that has this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I stumbled upon a similar (albeit simpler) problem myself.

I'm afraid you can't really get what you want - BUT it's easy enough to have a string variable that you use to store the directory you should go to. You could incapsulate it into a class, and voila!, you've got what you need.

Here's my class:

```
public class PersistentOpenFileDialog
{
    OpenFileDialog m_ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    string m_persistentDirectory = null;

    public PersistentOpenFileDialog()
    {
        m_ofd.CheckFileExists = true;
        m_ofd.CheckPathExists = true;
        m_ofd.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
    }

    public bool? ShowDialog()
    {
        if (m_persistentDirectory != null)
        {
            m_ofd.InitialDirectory = m_persistentDirectory;
        }
        bool? retval = m_ofd.ShowDialog();
        if (retval == true)
        {
            m_persistentDirectory = new FileInfo(FileName).DirectoryName;
        }

        return retval;
    }

    public string FileName
    {
        get { return m_ofd.FileName; }
        set { m_ofd.FileName = value; }
    }
}
```

It's very basic - it only decorates the methods and the properties I strictly needed, but you can easily add what's missing.

This class makes sure that the last directory persists across different `ShowDialog()`s of the same instance; however, when you shut the program down everything's gone and the OS will decide what happens when you launch next. It would be cool to make the directory even more persistent by serializing/deserializing to/from a file or the system registry.